# SqlDataAdapter does not fill DataSet

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I'm using VS2012 and SQL Server Express 2008.  I've boiled down my connection/query to try and find out why my `DataSet` is not being filled.  The connection is completed successfully, and no exceptions are thrown, but the adapter does not fill the `DataSet`. The database that this is pulling from is on the same PC and using `localhost\SQLEXPRESS` does not change the result.  Thanks for any input!

```
SqlConnection questionConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
questionConnection.Open();
String sql = "SELECT * FROM HRA.dbo.Questions";
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, questionConnection);
adapter.SelectCommand = command;
adapter.Fill(ds);
adapter.Dispose();
command.Dispose();
questionConnection.Close();
```

Connection String:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=CODING-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=HRA;User ID=sa; Password= TEST" />
```

Comment: Check data is there are not........... you will get data in ds.Tables[0]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try this:

```
SqlConnection questionConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString);
questionConnection.Open();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
String sql = "SELECT * FROM HRA.dbo.Questions";
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, questionConnection);
adapter.Fill(ds);

adapter.Dispose();
command.Dispose();
questionConnection.Close();
```

Comment: Can you explain the difference? "Try this" is not really helpful.

Answer (score 7):

It appears the answer has already been found, however, I am posting one anyway to advocate the use of `using` blocks, and also letting the .NET framework do the hardwork for you. Your 11 lines of code can be rewritten in 3:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
using (var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM HRA.dbo.Questions", ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString))
{
    adapter.Fill(ds);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is "HRA.dbo.Questions" an actual table?

Your connectionstring contains an Initial Catalog with value "HRA", and the SQL should only contain dbo.Questions as far as I know.

Comment: This does not matter here.Connection string property is just to connect to the server and DB.

Answer (score 0):

Check that you dont have the fill statement in another part of the code such as in the page load event.