# Cannot Add a Row Using SQL and CommandBuilder C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, sqlcommandbuilder

I'm doing this exactly (see [Using SqlDataAdapter to insert a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631054/using-sqldataadapter-to-insert-a-row)) but it doesn't give me the .ADD method

Here is my code:

```
var sqlQuery = "select * from CT_DETIMP where 0 = 1";
SqlDataAdapter tableAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, myConnection);
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
tableAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

var impRow = dataSet.Tables["CT_DETIMP"].NewRow();
impRow["TRANSCD"] = tranCode;
impRow["MISC"] = misc;
impRow["ADDENDA"] = addenda;

dataSet.Tables["CT_DETIMP"].Add(impRow);  // THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR IS 

new SqlCommandBuilder(tableAdapter);
tableAdapter.Update(dataSet);
```

I get the error DataTable does not contain a reference for ADD.  I'd be happy to do this another way but I can't use table.Adapter.Insert because I need my data to go into specific fields.

---

So I changed  dataSet.Tables["CT_DETIMP"].Add(impRow); to  dataSet.Tables["CT_DETIMP"].Rows.Add(impRow);   and now I am getting a null error on this line:   var impRow = dataSet.Tables["CT_DETIMP"].NewRow();

---

This code worked:

'            SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            myConnection.Open();

```
        var sqlQuery = "select * from CT_detimp where 0 = 1";
        SqlDataAdapter tableAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlQuery, myConnection);

        SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(tableAdapter);

        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet("CT_DETIMP");
        tableAdapter.Fill(dataSet,"CT_DETIMP");

        DataTable detailTable = dataSet.Tables["CT_DETIMP"];
        DataRow impRow = detailTable.NewRow();'
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13138615/sqldataadapter-does-not-fill-dataset

Comment: Pretty sure it is .Rows.Add

Comment: also DataTable is the underlying of DataSet for example `dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Add`

Comment: MethodMan -- that was the trick -->  rows.add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the line with the error to this:

```
dataSet.Tables["CT_DETIMP"].Rows.Add(impRow);
```

Comment: Oh no.  Now I'm getting a null error on 'var impRow = dataSet.Tables["CT_DETIMP"].NewRow();'    Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add to the [DataTable.Rows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.rows(v=vs.110).aspx) collection

```
dataSet.Tables["CT_DETIMP"].Rows.Add(impRow);
```